# How to properly limit movement based on collision

Tags: java, slick

I have a confusing problem on my hands. I've managed to get tile-based collision working, and I'm using the following code in my update loop to restrict my character's movement.

```
        for (Block b : grid.getSelectedRoom().map.blocks) {
            if (this.rect.intersects(b.rect)) {
                if (b.type.equals("wall")) {
                    if (this.direction.equals("north")) {
                        this.y = this.x + 1;
                    }
                    if (this.direction.equals("south")) {
                        this.y -= 1 * delta;
                    }
                    if (this.direction.equals("east")) {
                        this.x -= 1 * delta;
                    }
                    if (this.direction.equals("west")) { 
                        this.x += 1 * delta;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that if multiple keys are pressed at a corner, the character gets all wonky and clips through walls. I've considered checking to see if the rectangle *will* collide on key press before movement, but I'm not sure how I could do that since I have to deal with looping through every tile with collision. How should I go about limiting my character's movement?

Comment: There are so many collision response questions on this site, probably the reason they didn't help you is they're all too localized. This question is the same. Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: I don't really get it but shouldn't this forum be answering other people's problems? Just asking though...

Comment: Yes Xeon, it's about answering people's problems, but there's a line. If this site was filled with localized questions like this one, all of the really good questions that would help more people get ignored. People would stop coming to this site because it's just full of people asking how to fix their code. What would be the reason for people to continue answering those questions? When a question is too localized it diminishes the site. As with all of the other collision response questions on the site, this question is unlikely to be of help to anyone in the future.

Comment: This is ***NOT*** a forum!

Comment: hoho, save your exclamation mark bro, it's just a question. Chill! 
Ah, I see. Make sense I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check horizontal and vertical collision separately. Also you shouldn't need to loop through every tile for collision, you should only have to check the tiles the character is entering.

As a personal preference, I like to check for collision before applying movement. It seems to save a lot of headache.

Comment: why even try its a bad question they should ask in chat or watever

Comment: @G Some bad questions have good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the horizontal/vertical info. I'll experiment with that for a bit. How does something like "When W is pressed - check tile one to north - if it is blocked - don't move" sound?

Comment: Try it out and see what you get. For me, half the fun of programming is getting it close and then working to fix it.